# how many characters is allowed in phpmailer

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, phpmailer, html-email

I make email function in CodeIgniter and when I set `"mailtype = html"` 
I can't send long text but when I set `"mailtype = text"` I can send email in a long text. I don't know why?

I want to send email with `"emailtype=html"` because I want to use bold, italic, etc in my message

this my setting

```
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host'=> 'my IP address',
    'smtp_port' => '25',
    'smtp_user' => 'my email address',
    'mailtype' => 'text',
    'charset' => '465',
    'wordwrap' => 'TRUE'
 );

$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('helpdesk@acc.co.id','ITCareHelpdesk ACC');
$this->email->to('dpalevi@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('[ITCARE] Reminder Request Approval ITCare ACC');
$this->email->message('');
```

I try to use lorem ipsum in my message when my `"mailtype = text"` for check it, and I can send email, but when I use `"mailtype = html"` I can't send my message

Comment: post you code please

Comment: I add my code @AbdullaNilam

Comment: `'charset' => '465'`? That makes no sense at all! You need to define what actually goes wrong, and your code looks quite incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is you're not using [PHPMailer library](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). You're using [CodeIgniter mail](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html) function.

```
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host'=> '172.16.5.20',
    'smtp_port' => '25',
    'smtp_user' => 'helpdesk@acc.co.id',
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1', # can use utf-8 as well
    'wordwrap' => 'TRUE'
 );
```

---

Make sure your port works using `telnet`

```
telnet smtp.domain.com 25
```

---

**Q -** how many characters is allowed in phpmailer
**A -** As I know there is no limitation in SMTP mail

Comment: I try it and still can't send my message, I check my port and my port is not using telnet @AbdullaNilam

Comment: I check it and my port is working, and I still dont know why I can't send email with long text like lorem ipsum when my "mailtype=html" but when I change it to "emailtype=text" my message is send @AbdullaNilam

Comment: test with gmail smtp. I never had this kinda issue.

Comment: In the end I still use 'mailtype' => 'text', I read in the documentation codeigniter, if I want use 'mailtype' => 'html' I must  send it as a complete web page, I try make it, but still not working. thanks for you help @AbdullaNilam